# Chrome Rewrite of Host: in HTML GET

Tags: html, google-chrome

At some point in the past I had a plugin for firefox that rewrites the HTML headers being sent by your browser, specifically the "Host:" line in the HTML GET request.

I can't find this plugin online. Does anyone know a plugin/way to do this? I am looking for one for Chrome but any would work.

The specific reason for this is I am trying to work on a wordpress website which I just did a DNS change on. Until that DNS change goes into effect I can use the IP but since its a shared host the Host line isn't set right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your [hosts file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29) instead - as an added bonus, this method also works for other HTTP methods and other protocols.

Comment: ...and all browsers.